# How to achieve text surround view in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

problem:
i want to achieve the effect as flowing:

[image]

i try to use view as the rounded rectangle，but it can't use in Android.

```
<Text>
 <View></View>
 <Text></Text>
</Text>
```

i also try use image as the rounded rectangle, but the text align vertical bottom.

So now i don't know how can to achieve the effect

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
             <Text>
                <View style={{ borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#a2a2a2', borderRadius:6 }}>
                <Text > ADAFAF </Text>
                </View>
                <Text> styleborder Width style border Width style borderWidth style borderWidth styleborderWidth</Text>
            </Text>
```

[image]

Comment: in adr, it can't use view nest text

Comment: In question he has already mentioned that this doesn't work for Android. Android doesn't support View tag inside the Text tag, in iOS it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-start',flexDirection:'row', marginTop:10}}>
      <View style={{ borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#a2a2a2', borderRadius:6, height:25, padding:2}}>
        <Text> hhshs </Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{marginLeft:10}}> side content </Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={{marginLeft:10, marginTop:10}}>down content</Text>
  </View>
```

Comment: This does not wrap the text, for example if you put very long text instead of "side content", it will not wrap.

Comment: hi @necixy we can use style={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}} to wrap the text

Comment: If you add flexWrap on the View (whose flexDirection is "row) it will bring the side content text view down instead of wrapping the text.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't consider this a proper solution but this should work for longer lines of text:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'; // Version can be specified in package.json

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text> TEST </Text>
        </View>  
        {
        "lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit lorem ipsum dollar smit".split(" ").map(val=>{
          return (<Text> {val}</Text>);
        }) 
        }
      </View>
  </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {padding: 50},
  section:{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:"wrap", alignItems:"center"},
  button: { borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#222', borderRadius:6, padding:5, backgroundColor:"#eee", justifyContent:"center", marginBottom: 10}
});
```

The concept is to create multiple text components split by blank space, this would allow the text to break. Again it's not an optimised solution but android doesn't support View inside the text so this is the workaround. Unless we come up with some proper solution.

You can also checkout this expo snack:
https://snack.expo.io/rJpjWP_BQ

Comment: but this cause to render more times

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in answer, for sure this is not a very optimised solution but this gets the desired outcome until we come up with some solution with better performance.